# How to fetch NULL values in Mysql through joins?

Tags: mysql, magento, null, fetch

I want to **fetch NULL values** in **Mysql**.
My query is like this-:

```
Select sc.message 
FROM shipping_comment sc,
sales_flat_order sfo
where sfo.shipping_comment_id = sc.shipping_comment_id
AND sfo.increment_id = 100000429
```

so If for the order no. 100000429 if customer given comment then it is showing correctly like below-:

```
   message
   sample comment ok
```

but say for any order, customer didn't give any comment. Say for another id 100000430. Then in sfo.shipping_comment_id value is stored in database as NULL. So how to fetch NULL for sc.message so that my output will be for order no. 100000430-:

```
message
NULL
```

One more problem is that shipping_comment (sc) only stores comments for which there is comment for order & for those only generate shipping_comment_id. So if there is no comment for order, there is no existence of any data in shipping comment table for that order. & for table sales_flat_order(sfo) if there is no comment for order, it store value is shipping_comment_id=NULL.
So in that case where condition become-:

```
NULL=sc.shipping_comment_id
```

which is not taken by sc.message.

So how can I fetch NULL values in mysql table???
plz guide me.

Comment: Use outer joins. A good example is at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what is the problem with your query? For the given order no. 100000429, your query will return the message if there is one in "shipping_comment"; otherwise it will return an empty result set.

Anyways, if you want to retrieve all order numbers and their comments, if any, this query should help:

```
SELECT `sfo`.*, `sc`.`message`
FROM `sales_flat_order` `sfo`
LEFT JOIN `shipping_comment` `sc` ON `sfo`.`shipping_comment_id` = `sc`.`shipping_comment_id`;
```

It will need a LEFT JOIN to return all orders.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

You need a "left outer join".  See this question for detail regarding syntax and semantics.

> [What is the difference between "INNER JOIN" and "OUTER JOIN"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38549/sql-difference-between-inner-and-outer-join/38578)